# Drawing the phase portrait

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $\lambda >0$. Consider the non-linear system
$$
\begin{cases}\dot{x}=x^2\\\dot{y}=-\lambda y\end{cases}
$$

The aim is to get an idea of the phase portrait.

There are some things I can see directly:

- First of all, $(0,0)$ is an equilibrium.
- On the $x$-axis, we are moving to the right.
- On the positive $y$-axis we are moving down towards the equilibrium $(0,0)$.
- On the negative $y$-axis we are moving up towards the equilibrium $(0,0)$.

But what happens if we start with an initial pair $x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0$ in the four quadrants?

In order to get an idea, I determined the solutions:

$$
x(t)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}-t},\qquad y(t)=y_0\cdot\exp(-\lambda t).
$$

Concerning the solution $y$, if $y_0<0$, $y$ grows exponentially, if $y_0>0$, it decays exponentially.

Comment: $x(t)$ does not decay for positive $x_0$.

Comment: Do you mean it does not decay for positive $x_0$? If yes, I do not see what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.  For $t$ to go from 0 to $\infty$, $t$ has to go through $\frac{1}{x_0}$ first.  What happens there?

Comment: I see. $x$ tends to infinity there. -

Comment: I made a mistake for $y$, too. It decays exponentially, if $y_0>0$ and increases exponentially if $y_0<0$. Is it enough to know that to draw the orbits since $y$ will dominate?

Comment: I think it might be helpfull to plug one solution into the other. If you solve the solution for $x$ for $t$, you get $t=\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{x}$. Plugging this into solution $y$ yields $y=y_0\cdot e^{-\lambda\cdot(\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{x})}$.